# UIWebView black color at bottom increases with Animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, core-animation, facebook-pop

There are some posts, where UIWebView bottom is black and can be resolved by two simple ways.

```
1. Clear Background of UIWebView
2. Set Opaque to NO.
```

However, this only solves problem for static UIWebView which is not changing its Frame or Constraints.

In my case, I have a UIWebView, It is very simple Drag and Drop on Storyboard's ViewController's View. No Inheritance. I set Background clear and set opaque to NO.

It looks fine up to now. But when I apply animation, using Facebook POP library

```
1. SetOpaque = YES, With Animation is clips the UIWebView's content showing black color.



2. SetOpaque = NO, With Animation is clips the UIWebView's content showing nothing (a View or something comes in front)



-(void) setConstraint {

    _topConstraintValue = self.topConstraint.constant - 200;

    NSLog(@"Value is UP %f " ,_topConstraintValue);

}

- (IBAction)animateUp:(UIButton *)sender {

    [self setConstraint];

    [VSAnimation popChangeConstraintForBasicAnimation:self.topConstraint begin:0.5 newConstant:_topConstraintValue   withDuartion:0.5 isEaseInAnimation:NO withCompletionBlock:nil];

}




-(void) setConstraintDown {

    _topConstraintValue = 0;
    _topConstraintValue = self.topConstraint.constant;

    NSLog(@"Value is Down %f " ,_topConstraintValue);

}


- (IBAction)animateDown:(UIButton *)sender {

    [self setConstraintDown];

    [VSAnimation popChangeConstraintForBasicAnimation:self.topConstraint begin:0.5 newConstant:[self getAnimatableConstraint:_topConstraintValue] withDuartion:0.5 isEaseInAnimation:NO withCompletionBlock:nil];
}


-(float)getAnimatableConstraint:(float)constant{

    return  constant+200.0;
}

-(float)getReverseAnimatableConstraint:(float)constant{

    return  constant-200.0;
}
```

Where, method inside VS is as below

**//VSAnimation.m**

```
+(void)popChangeConstraintForBasicAnimation:(NSLayoutConstraint *) layoutConstraintToPopChange begin:(float) beginTime newConstant:(CGFloat) newConstant withDuartion:(float)duration isEaseInAnimation:(BOOL)isEaseIn withCompletionBlock:(void (^)(POPAnimation *anim, BOOL finished)) completitionBlock{

    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"constraints_changed_%@", layoutConstraintToPopChange];

    POPBasicAnimation *basicAnim = [layoutConstraintToPopChange pop_animationForKey:key];
    if(basicAnim){
        basicAnim.toValue = @(newConstant);
        basicAnim.completionBlock = completitionBlock;
    }else{

        basicAnim = [POPBasicAnimation animationWithPropertyNamed:kPOPLayoutConstraintConstant];
        if(isEaseIn)
            basicAnim.timingFunction=[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
        else
            basicAnim.timingFunction=[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
        basicAnim.toValue = @(newConstant);
        basicAnim.completionBlock = completitionBlock;
        basicAnim.beginTime = [self timeWithDelay:beginTime];
        basicAnim.delegate = self;
        basicAnim.duration = duration;

        [layoutConstraintToPopChange pop_addAnimation:basicAnim forKey:key];
    }
}
```

What is this black line/transparent line at bottom.
How to stop this from increasing when one animates UIWebView.

IMAGES:

SHOWING ANIMATION UP & ANIMATION DOWN.[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: UIWebView is a legacy API, that have a lot of problems. It's much better to use WKWebView instead, if you can.

Comment: @BorisVerebsky, WebKit also does same.

Comment: Is it okay for you to simply set the UIWebView's background color to white?

Comment: No, It will react same. I did that, I made opaque to NO. also same thing, some layer comes up, @DavidCheung, Should I upload a demo of this?

Comment: @VS, yes, please do, how about settings opaque to YES together with white UIWebView background?

Comment: It is fine when no Animation, as it removes black line, which is common issue in UIWebView,but when I apply animate, it increase. Let me upload zip. Do you know how to use PODs, as you have to run pod install command, as I have used pod @DavidCheung

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/s1232h9rb8as836/WebViewDemo.zip?dl=0  @DavidCheung

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@VS, After reading you source code, I saw the constraint of the 2nd webview seems to be set wrongly. After I removed the height constraint `WV2.height = 0.095 * height`, the problem disappeared. You have to set the WV2's height constraint properly.

Comment: Dear, I am setting proportional constraints, so it could change according to device on which code will run. So, why issue is causing due to this height?